# Contact Trigger update a contact field based on contact mailing country change

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger on the contact object which runs 'before insert' and 'before update'.

I have a custom text field on the contact object which needs to be populated based on the selected 'Mailing Country'. The problem I have is that 'before update', my trigger runs and sets the custom field based on the loaded 'Mailing Country', I need it not to be dependant on the loaded 'Mailing Country' but on the newly selected 'Mailing Country' which hasn't yet been saved to the contact.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Just have it load the data from trigger.new that's in the field for the new Mailing Country and compare it with the data from trigger.old. At the same time, you can also update the custom text field if they don't match. That should be your criteria for the update to the text field.

You can only compare the values in trigger.new to trigger.old in the BeforeUpdate as part of your criteria. In a BeforeInsert, whatever gets entered in the one field will need to be entered in the other as there's no history to compare since there won't be any data in trigger.old.